# How to access my instance variable in my partial

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble accessing my instance variable. My code is as follows:

```
# controllers/locations_controller.rb
def index
  if request.xhr?
    neLat = data.dig('northeast', 'lat').to_f
    neLng = data.dig('northeast', 'lng').to_f
    swLat = data.dig('southwest', 'lat').to_f
    swLng = data.dig('southwest', 'lng').to_f

    @markers = Location
      .where("lat <= ?", neLat)
      .where("lng <= ?", neLng)
      .where("lat >= ?", swLat)
      .where("lng >= ?", swLng)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render :json => @markers}
    format.js
  end
end


# view/locations/_map.html.erb
$.ajax({
  url: '/location.json',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: {
    "northeast": bounds.getNorthEast().toJSON(),
    "southwest": bounds.getSouthWest().toJSON(),
  }
})
.done(function(data) {
  // EDIT HERE
  console.log(data)
  console.log(<%= @markers %>)
  // END OF EDIT
  $('.results').html("<%= j render 'locations/location_results' %>")
});
```

When I console.log(data) after my ajax has successfully completed I'm getting my anticipated results, however when I console.log(<%= @markers %>) I'm getting empty results.  How do I get access to my instance variable?\

EDIT:

So I ended up passing a hash from my controller to my view like this:

```
# controller
renderPartial = render_to_string :partial => 'locations/location_results.html.erb'
respond_to do |format|
  format.html        
  format.json {render :json => {markers: @markers, partial: renderPartial}}
end

# view
.done(function(data) {
  if (data) {
    $('.results').html(data.partial)
    return addMarkers(data.props)
  }
})
```

This let me render my partial and have access to my instance variable with erb and also use the callback variable in javascript.

Comment: Where are you logging the instance var ? I dont see it on your code ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky - I've updated my code above.  I was logging my data in my .done method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up passing a hash from my controller to my view like this:

```
# controller
renderPartial = render_to_string :partial => 'locations/location_results.html.erb'
respond_to do |format|
  format.html        
  format.json {render :json => {markers: @markers, partial: renderPartial}}
end

# view
.done(function(data) {
  if (data) {
    $('.results').html(data.partial)
    return addMarkers(data.props)
  }
})
```

This let me render my partial and have access to my instance variable with erb and also use the callback variable in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can with the current code. 
You jQuery ajax is out of context, meaning, you are firing an ajax from client and the server returns some data using => `format.json {render :json => @markers}` hence the data returned from the server will be available to you in you done callback like you have already done.

There are two things you could do

1. Render partial from your action which will have access to the instance variable

   ```
   def index
     # Logic here 
     render :partial => "locations/location_results"
   end
   ```
2. Or you can create a view for each format you want to support

   ```
   def index
     # Logic goes here 
   end
   # Create a file with js extension in your views folder of the corresponding controller 
   # index.js.erb
   # index.html.erb
   # etc
   ```

   When you do this, rails tries to render a view with the corresponding request format. So if the request is of type `js` which ajax is, it renders `index.js.erb`.

And in your `index.js.erb` you could do this `console.log('<%= @markers %>')`. Basically you can write javascript in this file to manipulate your html. For example in `index.js.erb` I could also do this

```
   $('.results').html("<%= j render 'locations/location_results' %>")
   console.log('<%= @markers %>')
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm confused at your 2nd solution.  I don't quite understand how I would implement that.  As for the first solution, I don't know if that will work for me because I would like to render and re-render the partial( which is on half the page) and more information is on the other half that needs to be displayed too.

Comment: You can render partial in the view ? The answer clearly describes how a partial could be rendered in your `index.js.erb` file. You could render any number of partials in that.